# How to manage a many to many relationship from both entities in hibernate framework?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, associations, bidirectional

I have two entities Post and Tag. They are in many-to-many relationship. Post is the Owner entity and Tag is referencing Post entity using `mappedBy` attribute.

Now I can update tags using utility methods (`addTag / removeTag`) of Post entity but
what if I want to add/remove posts using the Tag entity?
For that, We can make Tag entity the owner of the association but I want to do this operation (add/remove) from both entities. How can I achieve this?

Comment: So, you just should create the similar `addPost / removePost` methods for the `Tag` entity.

Comment: Is it okay, to have utility methods both sides?

Comment: Yes, *both side of bidirectional association should be in sync*, if we perform adding / removing on both side we should have utility methods on both side.